# How to turn off keyboard and lid lights for asus rog ubuntu 20.04 in SLEEP mode?

Tags: hibernate, ubuntu, sleep-mode, backlight, asus

I have a ROG Strix G731G and I already downloaded and use the rogauracore from this repository https://github.com/wroberts/rogauracore.git.

I use the `sudo rogauracore black` mode and the lights are off and everything is ok.

It works fine when the laptop is on, but as soon as I enter suspension (sleep mode) the lights turn red and start moving (bleeding effect or breathing effect).

It's very annoying because I need the darkness to sleep and I don't want to completely shut down the computer.

Does somebody know how to make rogauracore work also in sleep mode? Or does anyone know a trick to **keep the keyboards and lid lights off during sleep mode**?

I've read that in Windows you can do this at firmware level with Armoury Crate, but I only have Ubuntu.

Thanks

PS: I use Ubuntu 20.04